# Add Data to Datagrid Without Closing new View (WPF MVVM) CRUD

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, crud

I'm new to MVVM and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem..

I have 2 Views (Caixa & CaixaDetalhes) where in the Caixa view I have a datagrid displaying all Caixas and in the second view it shows the details and user can "CRUD" but I don't want to close the view when updating or adding with the dialogresult.

My Views:

AssistenciasCaixas:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCaixas" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DataGridResultados}" ItemsSource="{Binding Caixas}" SelectedItem="{Binding CaixaSelecionado}" RowHeight="25" Background="White" >
           <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="PostoID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Posto.ID}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="IdUtilizador" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding IdUtilizador}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Posto" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Posto.Descricao}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Caixa" Width="90" Binding="{Binding DataCaixa,StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Eliminado" Width="100" Binding="{Binding DataEliminado, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motivo" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Motivo}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nº Caixa" Width="70" Binding="{Binding NumCaixa}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Exportado" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Exportado}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True">
                   <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                       </Style>
                   </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
               </DataGridTextColumn>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Observações" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Obs}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Utilizador" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding IdUtilizador}"/>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
```

CaixaDetalhes

[image: CaixasDetalhesView]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Posto:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" Margin="0,-5,0,0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="comboBoxPostos" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,5" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxProblemas}" ItemsSource="{Binding Postos}" SelectedItem="{Binding Detalhes.Posto}" SelectedValue="{Binding Detalhes.Posto.ID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Descricao"/>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Exportado para o Olisoft?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="35,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" FontSize="20"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbExportado" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Detalhes.Exportado, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5" />
                </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
            </CheckBox>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Data do Caixa:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" FontSize="20"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="dtPickerDataCaixa" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,15" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" DisplayDateStart="2015-01-01" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource resizedCalendarItem}" SelectedDate="{Binding Detalhes.DataCaixa, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Data Eliminado:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" FontSize="20"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="dtPickerDataEliminado" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,15" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" DisplayDateStart="2015-01-01" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource resizedCalendarItem}" SelectedDate="{Binding Detalhes.DataEliminado, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" />
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Número do Caixa:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtNumCaixa" Grid.Column="2" Height="28" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,15" Width="200"  MaxLines="1" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Detalhes.NumCaixa, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        </Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Motivo" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}" FontSize="20" Margin="0,-6,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="richTextBoxMotivo" Height="100" Width="655" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" BorderThickness="1.5" Margin="0,0,0,8" Text="{Binding Detalhes.Motivo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Observações" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource lblEditarForms}"  FontSize="20" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" x:Name="richTextBoxObservacoes" Height="100" Width="655" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" BorderThickness="1.5" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Detalhes.Obs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Stroke="#FF00256D" Grid.Row="3" />
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="4" Columns="4" Height="70" Background="White" >
            <Button x:Name="btnGravar" Style="{StaticResource BotaoGridOperacoes}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Gravar}">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="115">
                    <Image Source="../../Imagens/save32black.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="32" Height="32" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBtnGravar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF00256D" Text="{Binding Path=AddSave, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource BotaoGridOperacoes}">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="115">
                    <Image Source="../../Imagens/new32Black.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="32" Height="32"   />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF00256D">Novo</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource BotaoGridOperacoes}" >
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="125">
                    <Image Source="../../Imagens/bin2.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF00256D">Eliminar</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnSair" Style="{StaticResource BotaoGridOperacoes}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Sair}">
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100">
                    <Image Source="/HelpDesk Assist;component/Avancado/Imagens/exit32.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="32" Height="32"  />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF00256D">Sair</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
```

My Models:

Caixa:

```
public class Caixa : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;
        private Posto _posto;
        private DateTime _dataCaixa;
        private DateTime _dataEliminado;
        private string _motivo;
        private int _numCaixa;
        private bool _exportado;
        private string _obs;
        private int _idUtilizador;

        public int Id
        {
            get => _id;
            set => SetField(ref _id, value);
        }

        public Posto Posto
        {
            get => _posto;
            set => SetField(ref _posto, value);
        }

        public DateTime DataCaixa
        {
            get => _dataCaixa;
            set => SetField(ref _dataCaixa, value);
        }

        public DateTime DataEliminado
        {
            get => _dataEliminado;
            set => SetField(ref _dataEliminado, value);
        }

        public string Motivo
        {
            get => _motivo;
            set => SetField(ref _motivo, value);
        }

        public int NumCaixa
        {
            get => _numCaixa;
            set => SetField(ref _numCaixa, value);
        }

        public bool Exportado
        {
            get => _exportado;
            set => SetField(ref _exportado, value);
        }

        public string Obs
        {
            get => _obs;
            set => SetField(ref _obs, value);
        }

        public int IdUtilizador
        {
            get => _idUtilizador;
            set => SetField(ref _idUtilizador, value);
        }
    }
```

My ViewModels:

CaixasViewModel

```
public class CaixasViewModel : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Caixa> Caixas { get; private set; }

        public CaixasViewModel()
        {
            int utilizadorAtual = Properties.Settings.Default.userID;
            Caixas = new ObservableCollection<Caixa>();
            Caixas = CaixaData.GetCaixasUtilizador(utilizadorAtual);
        }

        private Caixa _caixaSelecionado;
        public Caixa CaixaSelecionado
        {
            get { return _caixaSelecionado; }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref _caixaSelecionado, value);
                Delete.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                Edita.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public DeleteCaixa Delete { get; private set; } = new DeleteCaixa();
        public EditaCaixa Edita { get; private set; } = new EditaCaixa();
        public NovoCaixa Novo { get; private set; } = new NovoCaixa();

        public class DeleteCaixa : BaseCommand
        {
            public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return parameter is CaixasViewModel viewModel && viewModel.CaixaSelecionado != null;
            }

            public override void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                CaixasViewModel viewModel = (CaixasViewModel)parameter;
                CaixaData.DeleteCaixa(viewModel.CaixaSelecionado.Id);
                _ = viewModel.Caixas.Remove(viewModel.CaixaSelecionado);
            }
        }

        public class NovoCaixa : BaseCommand
        {
            public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return parameter is CaixasViewModel;
            }

            public override void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                CaixasViewModel viewModel = (CaixasViewModel)parameter;
                Caixa caixa = new Caixa
                {
                    DataCaixa = DateTime.Now,
                    DataEliminado = DateTime.Now
                };
                CaixasDetalhesViewModel caixaDetalhes = new CaixasDetalhesViewModel(caixa);
                DetalhesCaixa dc = new DetalhesCaixa(caixaDetalhes)
                {
                    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
                };
                _ = dc.ShowDialog();
                if (dc.DialogResult.HasValue && dc.DialogResult.Value)
                {
                    viewModel.Caixas.Add(caixa);
                    viewModel.CaixaSelecionado = caixa;
                }
            }
        }

        public class EditaCaixa : BaseCommand
        {
            public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return parameter is CaixasViewModel viewModel && viewModel.CaixaSelecionado != null;
            }
            public override void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                CaixasViewModel viewModel = (CaixasViewModel)parameter;
                CaixasDetalhesViewModel caixaDetalhes = new CaixasDetalhesViewModel(viewModel.CaixaSelecionado);
                DetalhesCaixa detCaixa = new DetalhesCaixa(caixaDetalhes)
                {
                    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
                };
                _ = detCaixa.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

CaixasDetalhesViewModel:

```
public class CaixasDetalhesViewModel : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Posto> Postos { get; set; }

        public Caixa Detalhes { get; set; }

        public CaixasDetalhesViewModel(Caixa detalhes)
        {
            Postos = new ObservableCollection<Posto>();
            Postos = PostoData.GetPostosSimples();
            Detalhes = detalhes;
            EscolheFinal();
        }

        private string _addSave = "Inserir";
        public string AddSave
        {
            get => _addSave;
            set
            {
                _addSave = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AddSave");
            }
        }

        public void EscolheFinal()
        {
            AddSave = Detalhes.Id == 0 ? "Inserir" : "Gravar";
        }

        public Action DialogResult { get; set; }
        public Action CloseWindow { get; set; }

        public GravarCaixa Gravar { get; private set; } = new GravarCaixa();
        public SairCaixa Sair { get; private set; } = new SairCaixa();

        public class GravarCaixa : BaseCommand
        {
            public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return parameter is CaixasDetalhesViewModel viewModel;
            }

            public override void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                CaixasDetalhesViewModel viewModel = (CaixasDetalhesViewModel)parameter;
                viewModel.Detalhes.IdUtilizador = Properties.Settings.Default.userID;
                CaixaData.AdicionaCaixa(viewModel.Detalhes);
                viewModel.EscolheFinal();
                viewModel.DialogResult();

            }
        }

        public class SairCaixa : BaseCommand
        {
            public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return parameter is CaixasDetalhesViewModel viewModel;
            }
            public override void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                CaixasDetalhesViewModel viewModel = (CaixasDetalhesViewModel)parameter;
                viewModel.CloseWindow();

            }
        }

    }
```

Overall:

I can CRUD with DialogResult but I need to be able to insert/update/delete "Caixa" in the CaixaDetalhes View without closing the view

EDIT:
How can I Update the Caixa Model just when clicking the save button? I've try using "UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit" but when trying to change Caixa nothing happens..

I'm not using any framework and I'd like to keep it that way if possible

Comment: You must create an intermediate item for editing. The save command then commits the changes by copying the data to the real model that resides in the collection. That's all. On create, you create a blank item and only add it to the collection on "Save". On edit , create a copy of the original item, edit it and copy it back on "Save".

Comment: But how can I do that? I'm adding to the observableCollection in the CaixasViewModel when I close the CaixasDetalhes view like this : "if (dc.DialogResult.HasValue && dc.DialogResult.Value) { viewModel.Caixas.Add(caixa); viewModel.CaixaSelecionado = caixa; }". How can I add data through the CaixasDetalhesViewModel? I can add/update just fine to the database but not to the observableCollection

Comment: The CaixasDetalhesViewModel obviously needs a reference to the Caixas collection. Where do you show the dialog?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. When you create the dialog you also create an instance of the CaixasDetalhesViewModel. Simply add a Caixas property to the CaixasDetalhesViewModel and assign it before you set it to the dialog context or pass a reference of the CaixasViewModel to the CaixasDetalhesViewModel and let CaixasDetalhesViewModel call an AddNewCaixa(Caixa newItem) method, which actually adds the item.

Comment: Third option, pass a set of Add/Edit/Remove ICommands or delegates to the CaixasDetalhesViewModel. The advantage is that the CaixasViewModel can remain unknown to the CaixasDetalhesViewModel. I think the third option is the best.

Comment: When I'm inserting a new one its the public class NovoCaixa : BaseCommand, when i'm editign its public class EditaCaixa : BaseCommand, inside CaixasViewModel. And inside CaixasDetalhes view i'm doing private CaixasDetalhesViewModel _detalhes;
        public DetalhesCaixa(CaixasDetalhesViewModel detalhes)
        {
            _detalhes = detalhes;
            DataContext = _detalhes;

Comment: How can I implement the third option?

Comment: How do you pass the editable items to the dialog?

Comment: In the datagrid I have "SelectedItem="{Binding CaixaSelecionado}"" and in CaixasViewModel I have  "CaixasViewModel viewModel = (CaixasViewModel)parameter;
                CaixasDetalhesViewModel caixaDetalhes = new CaixasDetalhesViewModel(viewModel.CaixaSelecionado);
                DetalhesCaixa detCaixa = new DetalhesCaixa(caixaDetalhes);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to pass a reference of the save command and the current modified item from the `CaixasViewModel` to the `CaixasDetalhesViewModel`. Then let the `CaixasViewModel` modify its `Caixas` collection, as it is the owner.

You should not show dialogs from the view model. Show it from code-behind (see example below).

The following example should give you a raw idea about the pattern:
let the main view model create and initialize the dialog view model with a corresponding save command and the item to modify (add and edit). The dialog view model only exposes the item for modification to the user and executes the save command that it received from the main view model. The main view model knows how to handle the target item e.g., create new instance (create new dialog) or copy instance (edit dialog).

The main idea is to create a copy of the original item model that you want to edit. When the save button is clicked, the changes are committed by copying the new data back to the original model (edit a copy).

The example also makes use of the reusable `RelayCommand`, to help to improve readability by reducing code complexity. You can find the original implementation at [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic). Simply copy the short code to a class named `RelayCommand` in your project and use it instead of implementing new command classes for each command.

**CaixasViewModel.cs**

```cs
class CaixasViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Caixa> Caixas { get; private set; }

  // The "Save" command of the create dialog.
  public ICommand AddCaixaCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteAddCaixa);
  
  // The "Save" command of the edit dialog
  public ICommand UpdateCaixaCommand 
    => new RelayCommand(ExecuteUpdateCaixa, commandParameter => this.CaixaSelecionado != null);

  public ICommand RemoveCaixaCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteRemoveCaixa);

  // Clears the current EditSource by creating a new empty Caixa item
  public ICommand NewCaixaCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteNewCaixa);

  private CaixasDetalhesViewModel CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel { get; set; }

  public CaixasDetalhesViewModel GetEditCaixaViewModel 
  { 
    var editSource = this.CaixaSelecionado.Clone();
    this. CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel = 
      new EditCaixasDetalhesViewModel(
        this.ReplaceCaixaCommand, 
        editSource);

    return this.CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel;
  }

  public CaixasDetalhesViewModel GetCreateCaixaViewModel 
  { 
    var editSource = new Caixa();
    this.CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel = 
      new CreateCaixasDetalhesViewModel(
        this.AddCaixaCommand, 
        this.NewCaixaCommand,
        editSource);

    return this.CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel;
  }

  private void ExecuteAddCaixa(object commandParameter) 
  {
    var createdCaixa = (Caixa)commandParameter;
    this.Caixas.Add(createdCaixa);

    // Create a new temp copy to avoid editing the original instance directly    
    var editableCreatedCaixa = createdCaixa.Clone();
    this.CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel.EditSource = editableCreatedCaixa;
  }

  private void ExecuteNewCaixa(object commandParameter) 
  {
    // Update the dialog with a new empty Caixa item
    var emptyCaixa = new Caixa();
    this.CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel.EditSource = emptyCaixa;
  }

  private void ExecuteUpdateCaixa(object commandParameter)
  {
    Caixa editedCaixa = (Caixa)commandParameter;
    var originalCaixa = this.Caixas.First(caixa => caixa.Id == editedCaixa.Id);
    
    // Copy data
    originalCaixa.Posto = editedCaixa.Posto;
    ...
  }

  private void ExecuteRemoveCaixa(object commandParameter) 
    => this.Caixas.Remove((Caixa)commandParameter);
}
```

**CreateCaixasDetalhesViewModel.cs**

```cs
class  CreateCaixasDetalhesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Caixa EditSource { get; set; }
  public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
  public ICommand ClearEditSourceCommand { get; }

  public CreateCaixasDetalhesViewModel(
    ICommand saveCommand, 
    ICommand newCommand, 
    Caixa editSource)
  {
    this.SaveCommand = saveCommand;
    this.ClearEditSourceCommand = newCommand;
    this.EditSource = editSource;
  }
}
```

**EditCaixasDetalhesViewModel.cs**

```cs
class  EditCaixasDetalhesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Caixa EditSource { get; set; }
  public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }

  public EditCaixasDetalhesViewModel(
    ICommand saveCommand, 
    Caixa editSource)
  {
    this.SaveCommand = saveCommand;
    this.EditSource = editSource;
  }
}
```

**AssistenciasCaixas.xaml**

```xml
<!-- DataContext is the CaixasViewModel -->
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgCaixas" />

    <Button Content="Open Edit Dialog" Click="OnEditDialogButtonClicked" />
    <Button Content="Open Create New Dialog" Click="OnCreateDialogButtonClicked" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**AssistenciasCaixas.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class AssistenciasCaixas : Window
{
  private void OnEditDialogButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
    var viewModel = this.DataContex as CaixasViewModel;
    CaixasDetalhesViewModel caixaDetalhes = viewModel.GetEditCaixaViewModel();
    var dc = new EditDetalhesCaixa(caixaDetalhes);
    _ = dc.ShowDialog(); // Owner is automatically set on ShowDialog()

    // The following code is now handled in the CaixasViewModel
    //if (dc.DialogResult.HasValue && dc.DialogResult.Value)
    //{
    //  viewModel.Caixas.Add(caixa);
    //  viewModel.CaixaSelecionado = caixa;
    //}
  }

  private void OnCreateDialogButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
    var viewModel = this.DataContex as CaixasViewModel;
    CaixasDetalhesViewModel caixaDetalhes = viewModel.GetCreateCaixaViewModel();
    var dc = new CreateDetalhesCaixa(caixaDetalhes);
    _ = dc.ShowDialog(); // Owner is automatically set on ShowDialog()

    // The following code is now handled in the CaixasViewModel
    //if (dc.DialogResult.HasValue && dc.DialogResult.Value)
    //{
    //  viewModel.Caixas.Add(caixa);
    //  viewModel.CaixaSelecionado = caixa;
    //}
  }
}
```

**CreateCaixaDetalhes.xaml**

```xml
<!-- DataContext is the CreateCaixasDetalhesViewModel -->
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding EditSource.Motivo}" />
    <Button Content="Save" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding EditSource}" />
    <Button Content="New" 
            Command="{Binding ClearEditSourceCommand}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**EditCaixaDetalhes.xaml**

```xml
<!-- DataContext is the EditCaixasDetalhesViewModel -->
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding EditSource.Motivo}" />
    <Button Content="Save" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding EditSource}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Caixa.cs**

```cs
public class Caixa : ICloneable
{
  public int Id
  {
    get => _id;
    set => SetField(ref _id, value);
  }

  ...

  // Assumes that the property Posto is not editable via dialog,
  // otherwise clone Posto too (deep clone). 
  object ICloneable.Clone() => MemberwiseClone();
  public Caixa Clone() => ((ICloneable)this).Clone() as Caixa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a few changes and now I can insert/update to the datagrid and SQL without closing the Detailsview. I mess around with the code and as soon I add a new Caixa I get the ID of the new caixa but I want to know, is there a way I can call ReplaceCaixaCommand if I want to edit the record before I add a new one?

Comment: I mean everything is possible. But why would you want that? You must create an item before you can edit it. The create process is completed when you close the dialog by clicking on the save button. This adds the item to the collection and closes the dialog, am I right? Now the new item pops up in the DataGrid and is ready for edit. Or did I get the flow wrong?

Comment: In case you allow to create items in batches, like keep the create dialog open to create the next, and you want to edit the last created item you run into more "problems". You would have to store the history of the items you have created last while the dialog is open, so that the user can pick a recent item and review or edit it.

Comment: In this case you must add some logic to the ExecuteAddCaixa(). this logic must check if the item to add already exists e.g., by comparing the ID. If it exists you call ExecuteReplaceCaixa() to update the existing item. If you want to allow undo or discard, again you would have to create copies of the item. This means the items in the history (e.g., a ComboBox) must already be copies. Please tell me how your flow looks like.

Comment: I need it that way because sometimes I have to add a lot of Caixas (like 20 in 5 minutes) and exiting the dialog to open it again takes a lot of time :> I did something like this [1] https://i.imgur.com/b1ZoQ5U.png and now I can insert and edit. is there a way I can click "Novo" button in DetailsView to erase all data from textbox and give the ID 0 to Caixa?

Comment: The workflow is like always insert but if last one its still open they can edit.. Other ones they need to go to the datagrid. Does this image helps? [1] https://i.imgur.com/KRryLrl.png

Comment: *"is there a way I can click "Novo" button in DetailsView to erase all data from textbox and give the ID 0 to Caixa?"*: first, in the `CaixasViewModel` you must always store a reference to the instance of the `CaixasDetalhesViewModel` returned by the `GetCreateCaixaViewModel()` in a private property e.g., `CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel`. Now, when you click the "Novo" button you enter the `ExecuteAddCaixa` method. Here you can create a new `Caixa` instance and assign it to the `EditSource` property of the `CurrentCaixasDetalhesViewModel` property. This way the dialog receives a blank item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241062/discussion-between-enato-and-bioniccode).

Comment: I have updated the example to show you how to handle editing in the create dialog. Changes are in the CaixasViewModel class. I don't know how you close the dialog. But the close button must be handled by the DetalhesCaixa dialog. It should then close itself.

Comment: I have also renamed the ReplaceCaixaCommand to UpdateCaixaCommand and ExecuteReplaceCaixa to ExecuteUpdateCaixa as "update" describes the process better than "replace".

Comment: I have updated the example and introduced a dedicated edit and create dialog viwe and view model.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect now! Sorry for all the trouble